# SurfaceView для Android Lollipop

Tags: android, камера

Столкнулась с тем, что код для работы с камерой не работает на 5.1.1. Как необходимо работать с SurfaceView начиная с 5.1.1?

```
public class ViewCamera extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

SurfaceView surfaceView;
Camera camera;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
final int CAMERA_ID = 0;
File photoFile;
File videoFile;
String namePhoto = " ";
String nameVideo = " ";
File pictures;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    pictures = Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    nameVideo = getCurrentTime();

    videoFile = new File(pictures, nameVideo + ".3gp");

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

    SurfaceHolder holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                camera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {
            setCameraDisplayOrientation(CAMERA_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        }
    });

}

private String getCurrentTime() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    long milisecond = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    String str = Long.toString(milisecond);
    return str;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    camera = Camera.open();
    initSpinners();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    if (camera != null)
        camera.release();
    camera = null;
}

public void onClickPicture(View view) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            try {
                namePhoto = getCurrentTime();
                photoFile = new File(pictures, namePhoto + ".jpg");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photoFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
                namePhoto = namePhoto + 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.btnTakePicture:
        Intent intent = new Intent(ViewCamera.this, MapActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
}

public void onClickStartRecord(View view) {
    if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
        mediaRecorder.start();
    } else {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
    }
}

public void onClickStopRecord(View view) {
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
    }
}

private boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {

    camera.unlock();

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
            .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
    nameVideo = nameVideo + 1;
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();
        mediaRecorder = null;
        camera.lock();
    }
}

void setCameraDisplayOrientation(int cameraId) {
    // определяем насколько повернут экран от нормального положения
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        degrees = 0;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        degrees = 90;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        degrees = 180;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        degrees = 270;
        break;
    }

    int result = 0;

    // получаем инфо по камере cameraId
    CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);

    // задняя камера
    if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
        result = ((360 - degrees) + info.orientation);
    } else
    // передняя камера
    if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = ((360 - degrees) - info.orientation);
        result += 360;
    }
    result = result % 360;
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}

void initSpinners() {
    // Цветовые эффекты
    // получаем список цветовых эффектов
    final List<String> colorEffects = camera.getParameters()
            .getSupportedColorEffects();
    Spinner spEffect = initSpinner(R.id.spEffect, colorEffects, camera
            .getParameters().getColorEffect());
    // обработчик выбора
    spEffect.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setColorEffect(colorEffects.get(arg2));
            camera.setParameters(params);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });

    // Режимы вспышки
    // получаем список режимов вспышки
    final List<String> flashModes = camera.getParameters()
            .getSupportedFlashModes();
    // настройка спиннера
    Spinner spFlash = initSpinner(R.id.spFlash, flashModes, camera
            .getParameters().getFlashMode());
    // обработчик выбора
    spFlash.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(flashModes.get(arg2));
            camera.setParameters(params);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
}

Spinner initSpinner(int spinnerId, List<String> data, String currentValue) {
    // настройка спиннера и адаптера для него
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(spinnerId);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    // определеяем какое значение в списке является текущей настройкой
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        String item = data.get(i);
        if (item.equals(currentValue)) {
            spinner.setSelection(i);
        }
    }

    return spinner;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: С API 21 рекомендуется пользоваться [android.hardware.camera2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html). Пример реализации можно взять [здесь](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `TextureView` вместо `SurfaceView`.

Рекомендую также найти на Google Play приложение, OpenCamera - в описании указана ссылка на его исходный код, изучить его и сравнить со своим.